# Unique index not enforced on multiple columns - different behaviour MySQL vs. Oracle

Tags: mysql

This simple script:

```
create table test (a integer not null, b integer, c integer not null);
create unique index test1 on test (a, b, c);
insert into test values(1, null, 1);
insert into test values(1, null, 1);
select * from test;
```

runs successfully with MySQL and fails with ORA-0001 "unique constraint violated" with Oracle.

I am unsure what the standard says about unique index on multiple null columns but MySQL should probably behave similarly as Oracle.

See also http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/183630

Alexandre.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Question - Unique Key Not functioning correctly, or am I misunderstanding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429805/mysql-question-unique-key-not-functioning-correctly-or-am-i-misunderstanding)

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that this works in MySQL but *not* in Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL, by design, allows multiple NULL values in a column which has a `UNIQUE` index on it.

The `BDB storage engine` on MySQL was an exception, and it did not allow multiple `NULL` values in a coulmn, having UNIQUE index on it.

On the other hand, Oracle behaved differently with regards to `NULL` values. When you create a `UNIQUE` index on a single column in Oracle, it will allow you to have multiple `NULL` values, since `NULL` basically means an *Unknown value*, so two NULL values can't be compared to one another. More than that, NULL values are not stored in Index in case of Oracle. What this means is, when you create a `UNIQUE` index on multiple columns in Oracle, where two columns are `NOT NULL` and one column is `NULLABLE`, it will not allow you insert two records with same values, even though one column contains `NULL`.

Consider this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a NUMBER NOT NULL,
                   b NUMBER,
                   c NUMBER NOT NULL
                  );

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, NULL, 1);
1 rows inserted.

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, NULL, 1);

SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (RQ4151.UQ_TEST) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

This happens, since Oracle is not storing NULL values in the index, and so tries to compare the NOT NULL column values for uniqueness in the index, which fails, causing the error to be flagged.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how the other RDBMS vendors behave. In any case the SQL ANSI standards committee still has work to do.

Comment: Even though ANSI standards committee recommends something on this matter, it would be up to the vendors to implement the suggestions and at times, they differ on the implementation! :)